# Can connect to database, but no data from table will show

Tags: php, mysql, sql, phpmyadmin

I've searched and tried several techniques to no avail. I have been trying to make a table that will show information from my database. I can successfully connect to the database, but I cannot pull any information and display it. Could someone tell me where im going wrong? Here is my code:

```
<?php

$servername = "localhost";
$username = "";
$password = "";
$dbname = "";


$conn = new mysqli($servername, $username, $password, $dbname);

if ($conn->connect_error) {
die("Connection failed: " . $conn->connect_error);
} 

$sql = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM siege-leaderboard");
$result = $conn->query($sql);

if ($result->num_rows > 0) {
echo "<table><tr><td>1</td><tdp>2</td><td>3</td><td>4</td><td>5</td></tr>";

while($row = $result->mysql_fetch_assoc()) {
    echo "<tr><td>".$row["1"]."</td><td>".$row["2"]."</td><td>".$row["3"]." 
        </td><td>".$row["4"]."</td><td>".$row["5"]."</td></tr>";
}
echo "</table>";
} else {
echo "0 results";
}
$conn->close();
?>
```

I have also tried :
    while($row = $result->fetch_assoc())
and
    while($row = $result->mysql_fetch_array())\
With same results. Basically the code says "0 results" but theres information in the table, so im not sure whats happening =/

Comment: you don't have user and you don't have permission for fetch data .
user root as username and test you code again

Comment: $servername = "localhost";
$username = "";
$password = "";
$dbname = "";  define password,username and database name. its seems blank

Answer (score 0):

Convert $result->mysql_fetch_assoc() in $result->fetch_assoc().

You may also deal using $result->fetch_object() in order to use the field name instead of an array index while printing data. This will simplify your life if you will change your table structure in future.

Answer (score 0):

```
$query = "SELECT * from seller";
      $result = mysql_query($query);    
while( $row = mysql_fetch_assoc( $result ) ){
                echo "<tr>
                <td style=\"vertical-align:middle;text-align:center\" >

                <input type=\"submit\" class=\"waves-effect waves-light btn-large blue\" value=\"Edit\" name=\"edit\">
                <input type=\"hidden\" value=\"{$row['id']}\" name=\"sid\">
                </td>   
                <td style=\"vertical-align:middle;text-align:center\" >
                <input type=\"submit\" class=\"waves-effect waves-light btn-large blue\" value=\"Delete\" name=\"delete\">
                <input type=\"hidden\" value=\"{$row['id']}\" name=\"sid\">
                </td>   
                <td>{$row['id']}</td>
                <td>{$row['s_name']}</td>
                <td>{$row['address']}</td>
                <td>{$row['contactnos']}</td>
                <td>{$row['email']}</td>
                <td>{$row['img']}</td>
                </tr>";
              }
```

This will print the whole table in a table form

Comment: do check if user have privileges with all access

Answer (score 0):

This could work:

```
 $link = mysql_connect("127.0.0.1", "my_user", "my_password", "my_db");
 if($link)
   echo('Connected');
 else
   echo('Connection Failed');

$select = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM table_name");
while($row = mysql_fetch_array($select)){
  echo $row[attribute_1];
  echo $row[attribute_2];
  echo $row[attribute_3];
}
```

just insert your table design corresponding to your table data attributes in the while loop.
so until all the data in fetched from the table using mysql_fetch_array() the data will be displayed.

**Happy Coding :)**

Answer (score 0):

I made a very little change in your code so now you can test it at your end and I hope it will solve your problem with ease

```
<?php
$servername = "localhost";
$username = "";
$password = "";
$dbname = "";

$conn = new mysqli($servername, $username, $password, $dbname);

if ($conn->connect_error) {
die("Connection failed: " . $conn->connect_error);
} 

$sql = "SELECT * FROM siege-leaderboard";
$result = $conn->query($sql) or die($conn->error.__LINE__);

if ($result->num_rows > 0) {
echo "<table><tr><td>1</td><tdp>2</td><td>3</td><td>4</td><td>5</td></tr>";

while($row = $result->fetch_array()) {
    echo "<tr><td>".$row[0]."</td><td>".$row[1]."</td><td>".$row[1]." 
        </td><td>".$row[4]."</td><td>".$row[5]."</td></tr>";
}
echo "</table>";
} else {
echo "0 results";
}
$conn->close();
?>
```